# Initially I was running a React project and it was running fine. All of a sudden this error showed up. I slogged for hours but can't solve it

Tags: reactjs

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'C:\Users\91702\Desktop\react-validation\node_modules\serve-static'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
- install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib.js 1:0-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zlib_bindings' in 'C:\Users\91702\Desktop\react-validation\node_modules\zlib\lib'

Comment: remove `node_modules` folder and again do `npm i`

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete **node_modules** Folder & **package-lock.json**
2. Do **npm install** or **npm i -force**